# SQL derived value by a set of Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, derived, optional-values

Hi my table looks like this

[image: 1]

Combination of Rows with same S id is termed as a family.
Output should have a Calculated Tier code based on below derivation

Output put should be
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUgLU.png)

First time i am using Stackoverflow. I need a query in db2 and I can use the output as a report.

Comment: please provide desired output and avoid pasting screenshots

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

You need windows function as follows:

```
Select t.*,
       Concat('Tier ', count(*) over (partition by s_id) ) as tier
  From your_table t
```

Comment: Thanks for your Query but its not just Count of number of dependents ,if under a Sid there is a set of Relationship code i.e EE+CH it should give some kind of 'Teir+EE+CH' if its EE+SP the it should give 'Tier+EE+SP' ,if its EE+CH+CH then it should be 'Tier+FAM' like that basically some kind of string  for a set of combination of Relationship code. Hope I am clear about my question

Comment: What? I have written query according to expected output. You should make your logic clear in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks For you time REally Appreciate it.Is it possible to compare rows with in set of rows in table.Also I am writing query in Db2

Comment: Yes. It is done using windows function. You should really get your answer if you learn how to use windows function.